# is Apache Camel loads all routes once the server is Started?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am working on the `Apache Camel` + `Spring Boot` Project. What is the best way to debug this kind of project?

As Apache Camel is loading routes when the server is started, I am unable to debug it as it is already loading routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Camel builds all routes before context start, but you can debug camel routes by using [this](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/debugger.html). Also you can add .log() endpoints with DEBUG level to your routes or just add processes where you call `System.out.println()`. Either in a process you can use debug breakpoint.